# Расширение в Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, расширения

Добрый день, у меня в браузер очень часто автоматически устанавливаются расширения. куда нужно загрузить папку с Расширение чтобы оно появилось в браузере  ?

Comment: как то вопрос плохо сформулирован. Такое ощущение, что перевели гугл-переводчиком.

Comment: @KoVadim куда нужно загрузить папку с Расширение чтобы оно появилось в браузере ?

Answer (score 1):

Давно не делал расширения. Но Вам в любом случае браузер не позволит  автоматом включить расширения даже если они будут в

```
C:\Users\<ИмяПользователя>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions/
```

Придётся их включать в ручную.
*Хотя мой ответ : пальцем в небо. Вопрос не сформулирован от этого и не ясен*